# Module to Add/Manage Custom Fields?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, custom-field

Is there a Magento2 module similar to [Wordpress' Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) that allows admins to add and manage custom fields to CMS and other pages through the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for content and for the main entities (customers, orders, etc), you should try this one: https://www.advancedcontentmanager.com/

I've already used it in a few installations, allows creating custom content types with their own templates and fields

Hope it helps